# pdfx, beamer and lua(la)tex: is it possible?

Tags: beamer, luatex, pdfx

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
  \section{Présentation}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
  \section{Techniques}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
  \section{Mise en œuvre}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
  \section{Démonstration}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
  \section{Conclusions}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This example compiles successfully (albeit with the annoyances associated with using non-ASCII characters).
However, when I enable `pdfx`, I am plagued by these errors:

> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.730 \else

or (in this case using `a-1b`):

> ! Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key `pdftex,pdfa,pdfversion=1.4'.
>
> See the kvsetkeys package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.806  }
>        %

Is it possible to use `pdfx` with the `beamer` class?

Comment: Untested, but try `\RequirePackage[x-1a]{pdfx}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: `Beamer` bails out: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.`

Comment: It is possible to avoid the error `Option clash` by starting the document with `\RequirePackage[x-1a]{pdfx}
\documentclass[hyperref={implicit=false}]{beamer}`. However, after that the page dimensions are changed, so it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error for `xcolor` can be cured by

```
\documentclass[xcolor={cmyk,hyperref}]{beamer}
```

The main error about the minor version is cured by

```
\usepackage[pdf15,x-1a]{pdfx}
```

More difficult is to fix the `kvsetkeys` error, which is due to bad programming in `pdfx.sty`. I copied the file and changed all occurrences of

```
\hypersetup{\pdfx@...}
```

(where `...` is variable text) with

```
\expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@...}
```

because `\hypersetup` *doesn't* expand its argument. There are nine replacements to do. Since this is not wrapped in a macro, but is code executed during loading of the package, there's no other way than fixing the package.

File a bug report, the code is wrong to begin with.

***Disclaimer.*** Whether this makes a valid PDF/X file I don't know.

Comment: I have already sent a bug report to the authors of `pdfx` a few hours ago. I didn't find the option `pdf15` (so wrote no answer), but stumbled also over the expansion problem.